# Wailing Prison escape!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Why cant I get out of Wailing Prison?  It should not be this hard.  PS4 Console Skyrim seems broke.  Can anyone tell me how to get out of here.  I have the quest to find the hooded figure, but I cant get out of here to find the hooded figure.

Comment: What part about it is hard? This is a bit vague at the moment? What is stopping you?

Comment: Sounds like the quest progress reset or didn't update properly. What's your exact quest tracker text saying right now and can you describe the room you're in?

Answer (score 1):

From the description you wrote, you seem to have triggered a bug that has recently been fixed by [patch 2.02 for PS4](https://forums.elderscrollsonline.com/en/discussion/519021/playstation-4-patch-notes-v2-02). This patch was released on March 31 2020. Here is the fix description:

> Soul Shriven in Coldharbour: Fixed an issue where the Hooded Figure would not appear until after relogging if you created a new character and skipped the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get into the prison without talking to hooded figure?  They are the quest marker to bring you there.  I would definitely put in a work order so they can spawn you out to restart that quest!